# dodged geom_point in ggplots for presenting estimate of an errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code for presenting some measurements, their estimates and their CI:

```
ssi.oe.cutoffs.chart <- ggplot(data=oe.chart.data, aes(x=core_ot_code_mod, colour=cutoff))
ssi.oe.cutoffs.chart <- ssi.oe.cutoffs.chart + geom_hline(yintercept=1)
ssi.oe.cutoffs.chart <- ssi.oe.cutoffs.chart + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lcl95, ymax=ucl95, width=0.5),position="dodge")
ssi.oe.cutoffs.chart <- ssi.oe.cutoffs.chart + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=SIR, ymax=SIR, width=0.5),position="dodge")
```

`core_ot_code_mod` is a discrete variable, and the `geom_errorbar` works perfectly for me, showing 2 dodged errorbar with different colour, but I can't use the similar code to let the `geom_point` present the same way. And I am using another `geom_errorbar` as replacement, which is not very nice.

Can anyone here enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

geom_point requires explicit specification of width of the dodge.
here is a minimal example:

```
d <- data.frame(expand.grid(x=letters[1:2], co=letters[3:4]), y=runif(4))
d <- transform(d, Lo=y-1, Hi=y+1)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, colour=co)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.3)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lo, ymax=Hi), width=0.15, 
    position=position_dodge(width=0.3))
```

the width=0.15 specifies the width of the errorbar.
the width=0.3 inside position_dodge specifies the width of dodgin.